# Equivalent to MPI_Reduce_scatter but scattering among a subset of processors

Tags: mpi

Is there an MPI function equivalent to `MPI_Reduce_scatter` which performs the scattering only among a subset of processors? In case there is no such a function, which is the most efficient sequence of MPI calls?

---

For clarity, suppose that the reduce operation is the sum.
From

```
proc    sendbuf
1       a1 | b1
2       a2 | b2
3       a3 | b3
4       a4 | b4
```

I want to get

```
proc    recvbuf
1       a
2       b
3       
4
```

Where `a = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4` and `b = b1 + b2 + b3 + b4`.

---

### Workarounds

- Using two `MPI_Reduce`. The first reduces the `a`s and has 1 as root processor. The second reduces the `b`s and has 2 as root processor. However, it becomes heavy when there are many "letters" (and many processors).
- MPI_Reduce_scatter and set `recv_count[proc]` different from zero only if `proc` belongs to the subset of processors. However, when scattering the message there will be `n_proc` square handshakes (most of them useless beacuse no message is actually sent).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that two `MPI_REDUCE` calls is probably as good as you're going to get if you want MPI to do the reduction for you (which you probably do at scale).

Comment: Could you please comment also on my second guess?

Comment: Ah. That's a better way to do it. I forgot about that one.

Answer (score 1):

You may be overthinking this - in the case above, you could do it with a single reduce and a single send/recv pair:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int data[2], result[2];
    int rank, size;
    const int amaster=0, bmaster=1;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    data[0] = 2*rank;
    data[1] = 3*rank;

    MPI_Reduce(data, result, 2, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, amaster, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == amaster) {
        int tota = result[0];
        printf("%d: Total a = %d, expected = %d\n", rank, tota, 2*size*(size-1)/2);
        MPI_Send(&(result[1]), 1, MPI_INT, bmaster, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if (rank == bmaster) {
        int totb;
        MPI_Recv(&totb, 1, MPI_INT, amaster, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("%d: Total b = %d, expected = %d\n", rank, totb, 3*size*(size-1)/2);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And the natural generalization for multiple pieces of data is the scatter, so your intuition about `MPI_Reduce_scatter` is correct, but here because the two groups of tasks overlap (so you can't use an intercommunicator) but are not the same, you'll have to do a reduce followed by a scatter, and the scatter will have to be on another communicator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int ndata = 5;
    int data[ndata], result[ndata];
    int rank, size;
    const int amaster=0;
    MPI_Comm  scattercomm;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (size < ndata) {
        if (rank == 0) fprintf(stderr,"Too few ranks; exiting\n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,1);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<ndata; i++)
        data[i] = (i+2)*rank;

    /* create scatter communicator; all  of comm world must participate */
    MPI_Group basegrp, scattergrp;

    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &basegrp);

    int mpiranks[ndata];
    for (int i=0; i<ndata; i++)
        mpiranks[i] = i;

    MPI_Group_incl(basegrp, ndata, mpiranks, &scattergrp);
    MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, scattergrp, &scattercomm);

    MPI_Reduce(data, result, ndata, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, amaster, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank < ndata) {
        int item;
        MPI_Scatter(result, 1, MPI_INT, &item, 1, MPI_INT, amaster, scattercomm);

        printf("%d: Total = %d, expected = %d\n", rank, item, (rank+2)*size*(size-1)/2);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```